# Javascript - How to alter a property of a css class

Tags: javascript, css, properties

here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to the width of a particular div to be changed every time I resize the window. The div's class properties are in an external css document with class name '.nav'.

In HTML:`<body onResize="nav_resize()">`

In JS:

```js
var w= window.innerWidth, h= window.innerHeight;
var nav= document.getElementsByClassName('nav');


function nav_resize(){
 if (w<700){ nav.style.width= w-150;}
}
```

```css
 .nav{ background-color:#5F1C1C;
    position:fixed;
    float:left; 
    width:190px;
    min-width:85px;
    top:105px;
    height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1; }
```

I know I'm doing something wrong since nothing happens when try it in the browser.
 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('nav');` returns an array... so `nav[0].style.width= w-150;`

Comment: ... + you need an unit like `px` when setting `style`.

Comment: How could I add a unit in .style?

Comment: Like `if (w<700){ nav.style.width= (w-150)+'px';}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control this kind of resize events use [@media CSS rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    // CSS style for +700px
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    // CSS style for -700px
}
```

This will avoid you problems with resize both from smaller to bigger and opposite.

Comment: Yours worked, and it's simpler to use css for trivial stuff like this. Thank you!

Comment: thanks @MrP , i loved `@media` rule when I discovered it, simple, clear and works perfect when extreme and radical resizes are made during testing. :)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns nodelist. So either use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0];
```

or

```
document.querySelector(".nav")
```

```js
var w= window.innerWidth, h= window.innerHeight;
var nav= document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0];



function nav_resize(){
    if (w<700){ nav.style.width= (w-150)+"px";}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get changed window width in resize event listener and nav element from list.

```js
var w= window.innerWidth, h= window.innerHeight;
var nav= document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0]; // get nav element from list


function nav_resize(){
    w= window.innerWidth; // get updated window width after resize.
 if (w<700){ nav.style.width= w-150 ;}
}
```

Comment: Can you share complete html code that you tried. I have tried this and it works.